# why mapStateToProps will rerender,that is meaning call the render() in Component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

- I think in react frame, the view changes with Component's `state`,
- so I think when `mapStateToProps` run,and the component get a new `store's` `state`,
- which mean the `props` of the component change.
- according to `react` frame ,in this case, the view will not rerender unless the `this.setState` is called

Comment: I don't get the meaning of "frame" in your question. Can you expand it a little?

Comment: React component re-render automatically either if its props or its this.state change.

Comment: No, by default, React component rerenders whenever its states or its props changes. You can read more at the official document https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle. This topic is also covered in a lot of articles, so you can search for React lifecycle for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give one example.

**1)** You first load your component

**2)** You make changes on your component, thus changing your redux state for that component

Now, if you want to see the new props that are associated with this component you will see them in your 'render()' method. That's because the react component will re-render automatically if the props changed (as mentioned by Peter Ambruzs). The thing is, if you want to use these new props outside your render function, you will have to update your props(or your local state).

In this case you should use getDerivedStateFromProps (the new componentWillReceiveProps), for example:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  state = {
    stateExample: this.props,
  }
}

static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  if(nextProps.stateExample !== prevState.stateExample) {
    return { stateExample: nextProps.stateExample }
  } else return null;
}
```

This will update your local state with the new props that you just changed on your redux store.